# jQuery - if the checkbox is checked, stop unchecked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, checked

I am solving following situation - I have in table in database data and where by these data I have in HTML page checked or unchecked checkboxes.

I am wonder about the procedure, how to do, if I have checked checkbox, so how to disable to user unchecked this checkbox..

Exist some way, how to do?

Thanks a lot,
M.

Comment: make the checkbox readonly once its is checked, before rendering or on document.ready().

Comment: @Furqan: The `readonly` attribute cannot be used with checkbox inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After check on checkbox app attr disabled on checkbox.

```
.attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but one question yet - if I'll use this, so my checked checkbox will have gray color (as "disabled") - exist some way to disabled check the checkbox and have the "active" color of checkbox?

Comment: @user705586 I don't think you should make it as active. Otherwise user will try to click on it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked disabled>
```

Note that the `readonly` attribute in HTML cannot be used with checkbox inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want checkboxes that are checked to be disabled, you can use the `disabled` attribute:

`<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />`

If you want to disable a checkbox when it is clicked, with jQuery, you can do this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
      $(this).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: If you really do want to do it the jQuery way, at least use `$(this).prop("disabled", true)`. However, you should probably use `this.disabled = true;` instead — shorter and much faster.

Answer (score -1):

$(checkbox).attr('readonly', true);
Where "checkbox" is appropriate jQuery selector, don't use this code literally

Comment: The `readonly` attribute cannot be used with checkbox inputs.